# Apply Parallax effect into GridView

Tags: xaml, uwp, parallax, effect

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/motion/parallax
this is microsoft instruction to use the paralax they use the ListView to demo the effect
but my data is stored inside the Grid.View so can anyone show me how to implement into it ?
Microsoft said that we can use this with any element that contain the scrollviewer

Comment: Exactly, this works with GridView. Show your code if you want to know what is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ParallaxView` works with `GridView`. The `Source` property of [`ParallaxView`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.parallaxview) is for setting the element that either is or contains the `ScrollViewer` that controls the parallax operation. Here in your code snippet it bind the `ForegroundElement` to `Source` property but no such an element in.  You need to name the `GridView` as `ForegroundElement` .

```
<GridView
   x:Name="ForegroundElement"       
   IsItemClickEnabled="True"
   ItemClick="Grid_Clicked"
   ItemsSource="{x:Bind Icons}">
...
</GridView>
```

Besides this, the code snippet should work well. If you still cannot see the effects it may be caused by items count is not enough. `ScrollViewer` inside the `GridView` or `ListView` only be shown when the host control's layout space is being constrained smaller than the expanded content size, details please see [ScrollViewer in a control template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/scroll-controls#scrollviewer-in-a-control-template). You could try to add more items to check the effects.

Additionally, edit the question to add more details and avoid to put it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <GridView Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{x:Bind Icons}" IsItemClickEnabled="True" ItemClick="Grid_Clicked">
        <GridView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="data:Icon">
                <StackPanel>
                    <Image Width="200" Height="200" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Source="{x:Bind ImageCover}"/>
                    <TextBlock FontSize="16" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{x:Bind Title}"/>
                    <TextBlock FontSize="10" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{x:Bind Room}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemTemplate>
    </GridView>
```

this is where the data stored
and this is the parallax

```
<ParallaxView Source="{x:Bind ForegroundElement}" VerticalShift="50"> 

    <!-- Background element --> 
    <Image x:Name="BackgroundImage" Source="Assets/turntable.png"
           Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
</ParallaxView>
```